# Swagger-UI Customization in Swagger-Tools

Tags: handlebars.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-tools

I want to be able to modify swagger-ui and it is currently beng served through the instance in swagger tools, which is the current dist folder of swagger-ui. I would like to modify the templates and more through [main/templates](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#customize) which swagger tools doesn't have. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about customizing the look of swagger-ui you're going to want to edit the html/less code which you can find in `swagger-ui/src/main/`

Comment: How to change some text in swagger-ui, i saw template.js but did not find the exact place from where the text is showing.
e.g.
"fetching resource list: file://file://localhost/petshop.json; Please wait."
This is the first message it is showing, i want to change it but did not find the exact text.